# what could cause this error : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, path, pathlib

I'm very new to coding and Python so I'm really confused by this error.
Here's my code from an exercise where I need to find the most used word into a directory with multiples files:

```py
import pathlib

directory = pathlib.Path('/Users/karl/files/Code')

stats ={}

for path in directory.iterdir():
    file = open(str(path))
    text = file.read().lower()

    punctuation  = (";", ".")
    for mark in punctuation:
        text = text.replace(mark, "")


    for word in text.split:
        if word in stats:

            stats[word] = stats[word] + 1
        else:
            stats[word] = 1

most_used_word = None
score_max = 0
for word, score in stats.items():
    if score > score_max:
        score_max = score
        most_used_word = word

print(word,"The most used word is : ", score_max)
```

Here's the error I get:

```
 for path in directory.iterdir():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 1113, in iterdir
    for name in self._accessor.listdir(self):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/k/files/Code/exo'
```

What could cause this kind of error?

Comment: I notice that your code says `'/Users/karl/files/Code'` but the error says `''/Users/k/files/Code/exo'` (k not karl). It seems like the posted code did not generate the error. If your real code uses that second directory and it doesn't exist, you'd get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> here's what i guet
>
> ```
> for path in directory.iterdir():
>  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 1113, in iterdir
>    for name in self._accessor.listdir(self):
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/k/files/Code/exo'
> ```
>
> what could cause this kind of error ?

The most likely cause for this error is that there is no such file or directory, i.e. that the file or directory `/Users/k/files/Code/exo` does not exist.